# Cannot read property 'setParams' error in lightning application event which is calling from utility bar component in lightning console app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I have created one component and added to lightning console app as utility bar component.
And I have created an application event.
I would like to navigate another component when event fired with parameters.

But I am getting error like ***'Uncaught Action failed: [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined'***
Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <div class="slds-modal__container">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="/resource/demoAdapterLogo" align="center"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-form-element slds-p-bottom--medium">
            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-01">Username</label>
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <ui:inputText class="slds-input"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-form-element slds-p-bottom--medium">
            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-01">Password</label>
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <ui:inputSecret class="slds-input"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" aura:id="submitButton" onclick="{!c.handleLogin}">Log In</button>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({    
    handleLogin : function(component, event) {
        console.log('Controller handle click...');
          var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:phonePanelEvent");
        appEvent.setParams({ 'presence': 'Available'});
        appEvent.fire();  

    },

})
```

Event:

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Event template">
    <aura:attribute name="presence" type="String"/>
</aura:event>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi if you have custom event then you have to register it before use.
Please add the following line in your component to register event `<aura:registerEvent name="appEvent" type="c:phonePanelEvent"/>`
For more reference please have a look on salesforce docs for [Application Event Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_example.htm)

Comment: Thanks @Rishi for your response. But application event is not triggered. **Handled Component:**                                                                       
_`<aura:handler name="cmp" event="c:phonePanelEvent" action="{!c.renderPanelCmp}"/>`_                                                             
HandledCmp Controller:            renderPanelCmp: function (cmp, event, helper) {
      var typevar = event.getParam("presence")    }